# How to make a editable antd tree table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using a antd tree table and trying to make it editable. But somehow the code for linear table does not work for tree table. Does anyone know how to do it?

I have added all the required components but still when i click on the age cell... the input component does not appear.

I've added editable cell and editable row. Can anyone has ever tried to implement such a case?

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Button, Form, Input, Popconfirm, Table, Space, Switch } from 'antd';
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    editable: true
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
    width: '12%',
    editable: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    width: '30%',
    key: 'address',
  },
];
const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: 'John Brown sr.',
    age: 60,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
    children: [
      {
        key: 11,
        name: 'John Brown',
        age: 42,
        address: 'New York No. 2 Lake Park',
      },
      {
        key: 12,
        name: 'John Brown jr.',
        age: 30,
        address: 'New York No. 3 Lake Park',
        children: [
          {
            key: 121,
            name: 'Jimmy Brown',
            age: 16,
            address: 'New York No. 3 Lake Park',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        key: 13,
        name: 'Jim Green sr.',
        age: 72,
        address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
        children: [
          {
            key: 131,
            name: 'Jim Green',
            age: 42,
            address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
            children: [
              {
                key: 1311,
                name: 'Jim Green jr.',
                age: 25,
                address: 'London No. 3 Lake Park',
              },
              {
                key: 1312,
                name: 'Jimmy Green sr.',
                age: 18,
                address: 'London No. 4 Lake Park',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sydney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
];

const EditableContext = React.createContext(null);
const EditableRow = ({ index, ...props }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
      </EditableContext.Provider>
    </Form>
  );
};
const EditableCell = ({
  title,
  editable,
  children,
  dataIndex,
  record,
  handleSave,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const form = useContext(EditableContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (editing) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [editing]);
  const toggleEdit = () => {
    setEditing(!editing);
    form.setFieldsValue({
      [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex],
    });
  };
  const save = async () => {
    try {
      const values = await form.validateFields();
      toggleEdit();
      handleSave({
        ...record,
        ...values,
      });
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log('Save failed:', errInfo);
    }
  };
  let childNode = children;
  if (editable) {
    childNode = editing ? (
      <Form.Item
        style={{
          margin: 0,
        }}
        name={dataIndex}
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: `${title} is required.`,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input ref={inputRef} onPressEnter={save} onBlur={save} />
      </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
        style={{
          paddingRight: 24,
        }}
        onClick={toggleEdit}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;
};
const App = () => {
  const [checkStrictly, setCheckStrictly] = useState(false);
  const components = {
    body: {
      row: EditableRow,
      cell: EditableCell,
    },
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        components={components}
        dataSource={data}
      />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```